# How can I obtain with git log a series of patches that can be auto-applied?

Tags: git, patch

I want to list the [complete history of Linux](http://www.archive.org/details/git-history-of-linux) as a series of patches (in unified diff format), which I can process automatically from the first one to today's master. In theory, this would allow me to reconstruct the modern version from the log.  For this I am running the following command:

`git -c diff.renameLimit=30000 log -m -M -C --pretty=tformat:'commit %H %ct' --topo-order --reverse -U0`

Unfortunately, it seems that `git log`, either due to incorrect options that I give it or due to a bug, starts (after 1280 commits) outputting differences that do not match the preceding state, and therefore cannot be applied automatically (e.g. through patch).

As an example, running `git log -m -M -C --pretty=tformat:'commit %H %ct' --topo-order --reverse -U0 43acd296..9b7855ca -- drivers/usb/auerswald.c`
generates a diff that *patch(1)* cannot apply to the checked out system at revision `43acd296`.  (The problem is the same as the one occurring with the continuous log output.) In contrast, running `git diff -U0 43acd296 9b7855ca -- drivers/usb/auerswald.c` generates a diff that can be applied to revision `43acd296` without a problem.

Are there any additional options I should be giving to `git log` in order to obtain the output I want?  (I tried `--full-history`, but the problem persisted.)

Answer (score 1):

You should probably be using `git format-patch`:

> Prepare each commit with its patch in one file per commit, formatted to resemble UNIX mailbox format. The output of this command is convenient for e-mail submission or for use with git am.

The general syntax is:

```
git format-patch <revision range>
```

Where `<revision range>` is could be a range of commits, like `88236e3..40bc760`.

You'll get as output one file per commit, named sequentially.

Comment: Thank you!  Why do you think that `git-format-patch` will avoid the problem I saw with `git-log`?  Also, I'd like to specify a terse machine-readable output format, and `git-format-patch` doesn't seem to offer a `--format` option.

Comment: I was suggesting `git-format-patch` because it seems designed to do what you want to do (produce a series of one-commit-each patches), and unlike `git log` it is designed explicitly to provide *input* back into git.  I'm not sure how to reconcile "terse, machine readable" with "generate a patch", so I can't offer any suggestions there.

Comment: It doesn't seem that `git format-patch` is robust enough to export an entire repository. When I copy repos with `( cd "$1" && git --no-stat -M -C --stdout --root HEAD ) | ( rm -rf "$2" && mkdir "$2" && cd "$2" && git init && git am )` on the Docker Git repo I get the error `error: patch failed: filesystem.go:7 error: filesystem.go: patch does not apply Patch failed at 0062`

Comment: No problem, it was an interesting idea, that's why I tried it when the other method I came up failed.